# Why can I never form a club affiliation?

Tags: football-manager-2012

On Football Manager 2012, I am currently a club in the top tier of Croatian football.
I have three feeder clubs (all in Croatia). As I've been at the club for quite a while, the board allows me the option to pick my own feeder club.

Obviously, I want to expand my scouting knowledge; so I try to pick a club in  another country. I've tried for ones that are nearby e.g. Slovenia, Montenegro and these have a lower reputation than my club.

I've tried this many times now and the board have always failed to reach an agreement, even when I've had a change of strategy and gone for a Sierra Leonean side!

Why is this? Should I try something different?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to ask? Sorry. But I'll make some assumptions - Is this due to your demands being set too high?

Comment: @EfcSeany I don't think so. I'll make the request for a feeder club, the board agree and ask if I'd like to pick one, I select a club that seems a reasonable candidate (low reputation, no other affiliates, geographically close) and then I get a message in my inbox about a week later saying that the board could not form an affiliation.

Comment: Have you tried other clubs? Clubs that are not geographically bordered?

Comment: @EfcSeany As I've said in the question, I've tried nearby clubs, and those not so close.

Comment: I'm asking if you've tried clubs that are not near each other...
I have left an answer for you with some links that should hopefully be of some use.

Comment: @EfcSeany I must've tried getting a feeder about ten times now, different teams every time, from various locations and still nothing

Comment: The links in my answer should help you. They specify the easiest clubs to become affiliated with for best youth development.